# How can I Detect with JavaScript if Safe Exam Browser is on

Tags: javascript, moodle, safe-exam-browser

I am using chrome in safe exam browser, as a result I want to be able to test if the chrome is running in safe exam browser or not. Please is there a way I can use js to know if safe exam browser is running.
Thank you

Comment: According to what I've gleaned in a few seconds from Google, Safe Exam Browser is not Chrome but an entirely separate browser.  Some versions of it do use Chromium, which is a part of Chrome but not Chrome itself.

Comment: While this question does not make much sense, it should be noted that usage of Safe Exam Browser can be verified on the server-side (e.g. PHP). Website should not be served if HTTP request header "X-SafeExamBrowser-ConfigKeyHash" is not present. But since HTTP request headers can be quite easily added to traditional browsers, the server should also confirm that the correct SHA256 value is being sent.